# Super Diode Simulation Behavior

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes

Im trying to understand how a super diode works. I understand that when the input is negative, the opamp output is positive, this forward biases the diode, and sends all of the current to the opamp output. What i dont understand is the simulation results i am seeing. It takes a while for the negative swing to be rectified. This happens regardless of frequency or input voltage. Does someone know why this is happening? I am using an ideal OpAmp in this simulation.[image: red is output at top node. Blue is input.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question as i looked deeper into it. From the text book:

The rectifier circuit shown above has the property that for positive inputs the operational amplifier output saturates in the negative direction.

– The op-amp output voltage is required to change instantaneously from this saturated voltage, (Vs-) to +0.6 V when the input waveform passes through zero.

– Because of the limited slew rate of real operational amplifiers this cannot occur, and the output waveform will not be a precisely rectified version of the input waveform as the frequency of the input sinusoid is increased.

Ill leave this here in case someone has the same question in the future.

Comment: As an FYI, the time for an OP-amp to come out of **saturation** can be much, much longer than would be predicted from the slew rate.

Comment: Fair enough, but 2 msec? What the bleep kind of model is being used?

Comment: WhatRoughBeast, i think Sphero answered this discrepancy in his comment above